# How can I build an APK in Android?

Tags: java, android, binary, apk, android-manifest

I have everything needed for building an apk in my app's assets `(dex file grabbed from android studio output,/res, android.jar, Original AndroidManifest.xml, keystore and...)` 
 I can package them to an APK on my computer using `aapt`, but `aapt` is not available on Android. 
 
I tried `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("aapt")` but it returns an error since aapt is not available in android

I just need to package them as an APK and then zipalign & sign it. 
I can include something like `aapt` in my app, but i don't know how to use it. Please guide me to the right direction.
 (Do i need binaries for arm too? if yes, where do i find them?)

Is there any other way?

This question is **NOT** duplicate of any other question. I need to do this in Android. (I mean runtime)
Not on a computer.

Answer (score 1):

When AndroidManifest.xml is compiled, references to resources are replced with some indexes in the resource table (resources.arsc file). Thus the binary AndroidManifest.xml is rather useless without resources.arsc and not portable.

If you still need to convert a text AndroidManifest.xml to the binary form, try to use [App Builder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.serakont.appbuilder2). Rename your file to manifest.xml and put it in res/xml folder of your app files. Then build the app, unzip the apk, and you will have the file res/xml/manifest.xml in the binary form.

Comment: I have included everything needed for building an apk in my app. like /res. But i need to do this on my own app. Not on a separate app

Comment: Then I guess you will need to adapt the aapt source code (or part of it): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/tools/aapt